# orthogonal similarity transformation of a diagonal matrix by a permutation matrix: reverse direction

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations, orthogonal-matrices

$
\newcommand{\matP}{\mathbf{P}}
\newcommand{\matD}{\mathbf{D}}
\newcommand{\summe}[2]{\sum\limits_{#1}^{#2}}
\newcommand{\matQ}{\mathbf{Q}}
$

I have a question (also somewhat related to my previous question [properties of orthogonal similarity transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3355046/702757)). The following is known:

Let $\matP$ be a permutation matrix and $\matD$ a diagonal
matrix. Then $\matP^T \matD \matP$ is a diagonal matrix with permuted
diagonal elements.

I present my own proof below.

My question is: Does the reverse statement also hold: Given two diagonal matrices $\matD$ and $\matD'$ which have permuted diagonal entries and are interrelated by an orthogonal similarity transformation $\matQ^T \matD \matQ = \matD'$ (where $\matQ$ is orthogonal), is $\matQ$ always a permutation matrix or are there other solutions?

(Plus: Does the reverse statement depend on whether we have pairwise different diagonal elements or not?)

Thanks!

Proof (forward direction): Let $\pi(i)$ be the permuted index to index $i$. Then
\begin{eqnarray}
  (\matP)_{ij}   &=& (\delta_{i,\pi(j)})_{ij}\\
  (\matP^T)_{ij} &=& (\delta_{j,\pi(i)})_{ij}\\
  (\matD)_{ij}   &=& (d_i \delta_{ij})_{ij}.
\end{eqnarray}
We form the product $\matP^T\matD$
\begin{eqnarray}
  (\matP^T\matD)_{ij}
  &=& \summe{k}{} (\matP^T)_{ik} (\matD)_{kj}\\
  &=& \summe{k}{} \delta_{k,\pi(i)} d_k \delta_{kj}\\
  &=& \delta_{j,\pi(i)} d_j
\end{eqnarray}
and then multiply by $\matP$:
\begin{eqnarray}
  ((\matP^T\matD)\matP)_{ij}
  &=& \summe{k}{} (\matP^T\matD)_{ik} (\matP)_{kj}\\
  &=& \summe{k}{} \delta_{k,\pi(i)} d_k \delta_{k,\pi(j)}\\
  &=& d_{\pi(i)} \delta_{\pi(i),\pi(j)}.
\end{eqnarray}
We see from $\delta_{\pi(i),\pi(j)}$ that all off-diagonal elements
are zero (since $\pi(i) \neq \pi(j)$ for $i \neq j$). The diagonal
elements are $d_{\pi(i)}$ and thus the permuted diagonal entries of
$\matD$.

Comment: I think the forward direction also holds for signed permutation matrices $\mathbf{P}' = \mathbf{\Xi} \mathbf{P}$ where $\mathbf{\Xi}$ is a diagonal sign matrix with elements $\pm 1$ and $\mathbf{P}$ is a standard permutation matrix (entries $1$). Thus the reverse direction would also yield a signed permutation matrix.

Comment: This problem seems to be a variation of another one of my questions which is meanwhile solved: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3412983/702757