# vectors simultaneously orthogonal in two different bilinear forms with diagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, bilinear-form, orthogonal-matrices

I'm interested in the orthogonal similarity transformation of diagonal matrices, see also my previous questions [properties of orthogonal similarity transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3355046/702757) and
[orthogonal similarity transformation of a diagonal matrix by a permutation matrix: reverse direction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3362592/702757). Assume that $\mathbf{D}$ is a diagonal matrix with positive and pairwise different elements $d_1 > \ldots > d_n > 0$ and $\mathbf{Q}$ an orthogonal matrix. If the orthogonal similarity transformation $\mathbf{Q}^T \mathbf{D} \mathbf{Q}$ is a diagonal matrix, we have expressions $$\mathbf{q}_i^T \mathbf{D} \mathbf{q}_j = 0$$ for the off-diagonal elements ($i \neq j$). At the same time, we have $$\mathbf{q}_i^T \mathbf{q}_j = \mathbf{q}_i^T \mathbf{I} \mathbf{q}_j = 0$$ for these elements, and $\|\mathbf{q}_i\| = 1$.

My guess is that unit vectors $\mathbf{q}_i$ and $\mathbf{q}_j$ can only be orthogonal in both bilinear forms (i.e. both expressions above are zero) if they have an element $\pm 1$.

Does anyone have a counter-example or an idea for a proof? Can the proof address individual elements $(i,j)$ or would we have to consider all $(i,j)$? Would the conjectured property be lost with different assumptions on $\mathbf{D}$, i.e. if some elements of $\mathbf{D}$ are identical or if some are negative?

I'm grateful for any ideas.

---

I made a bit of progress, but got stuck at a later point.

$
\newcommand{\matQ}{\mathbf{Q}}
\newcommand{\matD}{\mathbf{D}}
\newcommand{\matC}{\mathbf{C}}
\newcommand{\vecz}{\mathbf{z}}
\newcommand{\vecq}{\mathbf{q}}
\newcommand{\vecp}{\mathbf{p}}
\newcommand{\pmat}[1]{\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}
\newcommand{\vecnull}{\mathbf{0}}
$

In the following I give up the sorting assumption of the diagonal elements.

We first look at the system of equations for two columns $\vecq$ and
$\vecp$ of $\matQ$:

\begin{eqnarray}
  \vecq^T \matD \vecp &=& 0\\
  \vecq^T \vecp &=& 0.
\end{eqnarray}

We can transform this system into a homogeneous linear system

\begin{equation}
  \pmat{
    d_1 & d_2 & d_3 & \ldots & d_n\\
    1 & 1 & 1 & \ldots & 1}
  \pmat{
    z_1\\
    \vdots\\
    z_n}
=
\pmat{0\\0}
\end{equation}

where $z_i = q_i p_i$. We transform the coefficient matrix

\begin{equation}
  \matC =
  \pmat{
    d_1 & d_2 & d_3 & \ldots & d_n\\
    1 & 1 & 1 & \ldots & 1}
\end{equation}

into reduced row echelon form: We normalize $d'_i = d_i / d_1$,

\begin{equation}
  \pmat{
    1 & d'_2 & d'_3 & \ldots & d'_n\\
    1 & 1 & 1 & \ldots & 1},
\end{equation}

subtract the first row from the second,

\begin{equation}
  \pmat{
    1 & d'_2 & d'_3 & \ldots & d'_n\\
    0 & 1-d'_2 & 1-d'_3 & \ldots & 1-d'_n},
\end{equation}

normalize the second row,

\begin{equation}
  \pmat{
    1 & d'_2 & d'_3 & \ldots & d'_n\\
    0 & 1 & \frac{1-d'_3}{1-d'_2} & \ldots & \frac{1-d'_n}{1-d'_2}},
\end{equation}

and subtract a scaled version of the second row from the first

\begin{equation}
  \pmat{
    1 & 0 & d'_3 - \frac{1-d'_3}{1-d'_2} d'_2 & \ldots & d'_n - \frac{1-d'_n}{1-d'_2} d'_2\\
    0 & 1 & \frac{1-d'_3}{1-d'_2} & \ldots & \frac{1-d'_n}{1-d'_2}}.
\end{equation}

We introduce for $i \geq 3$

\begin{eqnarray}
  a_i
  &:=&
  d'_i - \frac{1-d'_i}{1-d'_2} d'_2
  =
  \frac{d'_i (1-d'_2) - (1-d'_i) d'_2}{1-d'_2}
  =
  \frac{d'_i - d'_2}{1-d'_2}\\
  %
  b_i
  &:=&
  \frac{1-d'_i}{1-d'_2}
\end{eqnarray}

and obtain the reduced row echelon form

\begin{equation}
  \matC'
  =
  \pmat{
    1 & 0 & a_3 & \ldots & a_n\\
    0 & 1 & b_3 & \ldots & b_n}.
\end{equation}

For $d_i \neq d_j\, \forall i \neq j$ we see that $1-d'_i \neq 0\,
\forall i \geq 2$, thus the denominators are defined and $b_i \neq
0\, \forall i \geq 3$ and $a_i \neq 0\, \forall i \geq 3$.

(This paragraph considers violations of the assumption of pairwise different elements in $\matD$. It may be useful later. If $\exists i,j\,(i\neq j): d_i = d_j$, we have to distinguish two
cases. If all $d_i$ are equal, then the $z_i$ can be chosen
arbitrarily under the constraint $\sum_{i=1}^n z_i = 0$. If there is
at least one pair of diagonal elements which differ from each other,
we can select them w.l.o.g. to be $d_1$ and $d_2$, thus $d_1 \neq
d_2$ and $1-d'_2 \neq 0$. In addition, we select the diagonal
elements such that $\exists i\,(i\geq 3): d_2 = d_i$. In this case
we have $a_i = 0$. If also $\exists j\,(j\geq 3): d_1 = d_j$, we
also have $b_j = 0$. The case $a_i = b_i = 0$ is not possible.)

We now determine the null space of $\matC$. From $\matC' \vecz =
\vecnull$ we obtain

\begin{equation}
  \begin{matrix}
     z_1 &     & + z_3 a_3 & \ldots & + z_n a_n & = 0\\
         & z_2 & + z_3 b_3 & \ldots & + z_n b_n & = 0
  \end{matrix}
\end{equation}

where $z_3,\ldots,z_n$ are free parameters. This leads to

\begin{equation}
  \vecz = \pmat{
    -z_3 a_3 & -z_4 a_4 & \ldots  & -z_n a_n\\
    -z_3 b_3 & -z_4 b_4 & \ldots  & -z_n b_n\\
     z_3     &          &        &          \\
             &  z_4     &        &          \\
             &          & \ddots &          \\
             &          &        &  z_n
  }
\end{equation}

(note that this is not a matrix, but a vector written such that each
$z_i$ appears in a separate column) thus the null space is spanned
by the columns of the $n \times (n-2)$ matrix

\begin{equation}
  \pmat{
    -a_3 & -a_4 & \ldots & -a_n\\
    -b_3 & -b_4 & \ldots & -b_n\\
     1   &     &         &     \\
         &  1  &         &     \\
         &     & \ddots &      \\
         &     &        &   1
  }.
\end{equation}

Clearly, we can find a $\vecz \neq \vecnull$ such that both bilinear forms become zero. Therefore,
individual vectors $\vecq, \vecp$ fulfilling both equations are not
necessarily vectors with a single non-zero element in different
positions: Assume that $z_i \neq 0$, then $q_i \neq 0$ and
$p_i \neq 0$.

Thus we obviously have to consider the entire matrix $\matQ$:

\begin{eqnarray}
  \vecq_i^T \matD \vecq_j &=& 0\quad \forall i \neq j\\
  \vecq_i^T \vecq_j &=& 0 \quad \forall i \neq j.
\end{eqnarray}

If we could show that only $\vecz = \vecnull$ allows to fulfill all
these equations, we
could demonstrate that all vectors $\vecq_i$ can only have exactly
one non-zero element (which has to be $\pm 1$ since the vectors are
unit vectors) which appears in different positions. The argument
proceeds as follows: If $z_k = q_{i,k} q_{j,k} = 0$ for all $k$,
then $\vecq_i$ has zero elements where $\vecq_j$ has non-zero
elements and vice versa. Assume that one vector $\vecq_i$ has more
than one non-zero element. Since the remaining $n-1$ vectors
$\vecq_j$ ($j \neq i$) have at least one non-zero element (as they
are unit vectors), it would not be possible to find $n-1$ other
vectors $\vecq_j$ which have their non-zero element at the $n-2$
remaining zero positions of $\vecq_i$.

Any ideas how to show this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. Then $A$ is diagonal if and only if each of the standard basis vectors $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ is an eigenvector of $A$. If $Q$ is an invertible matrix then $Q^{-1} A Q$ is diagonal if and only if the columns of $Q$ are eigenvectors of $A$.

In your case, you have a diagonal matrix $D$ with distinct entries, meaning that each standard basis vector $e_i$ is an eigenvector. Because the eigenvalues are distinct, *every eigenvector is a multiple of some $e_i$*. This means that when you suppose that $Q^{-1} D Q$ is diagonal for some invertible matrix $Q$, you already know that the columns of $Q$ must contain multiples of the eigenvectors $e_i$. For example, a potential $Q$ could look like
$$ Q = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 6 & 0 \\ -\sqrt{2} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}. $$

Now apply the fact that your $Q$ is orthogonal, and so every entry must be $\pm 1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, I'm still struggling with some conditions and with the "if-and-only-ifs". Let me separate the two directions in each of the two statements in your first paragraph: "If $A$ is diagonal then basis vectors are EV of $A$" holds, but only if the diagonal elements are pairwise different. "If basis vectors are EV of $A$ then $A$ is diagonal" holds (spectral decomposition). "If columns of $Q$ are EV of $A$ then $Q^{-1}A Q$ is diagonal" holds (spectral decomposition). However, how do you show that "if $Q^{-1}A Q$ is diagonal then columns of $Q$ are EV of $A$"?

Comment: @Ralf To be honest, I think of $A$ and $Q^{-1} A Q$ as being the matrices underlying the same linear operator, where $A$ is the matrix in the standard basis and $Q^{-1} A Q$ is the matrix in another basis. A bit of thinking shows that this other basis must be the columns of $Q$. But we can also see this directly. Let the columns of $Q$ be $q_1, \ldots, q_n$, and suppose $A q_1 = a_1 q_1 + \cdots + a_n q_n$. Then $Q^{-1} A Q e_1 = Q^{-1} A q_1 = Q^{-1} (a_1 q_1 + \cdots + a_n q_n) = a_1 e_1 + \cdots a_n e_n$. But if $Q^{-1} A Q$ is diagonal, than that final answer must just be $a_1 e_1$...

Comment: ... and so we have $a_2 = \cdots = a_n = 0$. Hence $A q_1 = a_1 q_1$ and so $q_1$ is an eigenvector of $A$. The same logic applies for any of the $q_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to Joppy for the proof. I rewrote the proof in my
notation, I hope I got all the steps right:

$$
\newcommand{\matD}{\mathbf{D}}
\newcommand{\matQ}{\mathbf{Q}}
\newcommand{\matXi}{{\mathbf\Xi}}
\newcommand{\matP}{\mathbf{P}}
\newcommand{\matI}{\mathbf{I}}
\newcommand{\vece}{\mathbf{e}}
\newcommand{\vecq}{\mathbf{q}}
\newcommand{\vecv}{\mathbf{v}}
\newcommand{\vecnull}{\mathbf{0}}
\newcommand{\pmat}[1]{\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}
$$

What we ultimately prove is the following Lemma:

Let $\matD$ be a diagonal matrix with non-zero and pairwise
different entries. Let $\matQ$ be an orthogonal matrix. If $\matQ^T
\matD \matQ$ is diagonal then $\matQ = \matP'$ where $\matP' = \matXi
\matP$ is a signed permutation matrix ($\matXi$ is a diagonal sign
matrix with entries $\pm 1$, $\matP$ is a permutation matrix).

(I'm not sure whether the requirement "non-zero" is necessary.)

Proof:

Statement 1: The eigenvectors of the diagonal matrix $\matD$ with
pairwise different, non-zero entries are the basis vectors
$\pm\vece_i$, $i=1,\ldots,n$. Proof: The characteristic equation
$\det\{\matD - \lambda \matI\} = 0$ leads to $\lambda_i = d_i$. The
eigenvector equation $(\matD - \lambda_i \matI) \vecv_i = \vecnull$
becomes $(\matD - d_i \matI) \vecv_i = \vecnull$ which leads to the
solution $(\vecv_i)_i = \pm 1$ and $(\vecv_i)_j = 0$, $\forall j\neq
i$, and thus $\vecv_i = \pm\vece_i$ which concludes the proof of
statement 1.

Statement 2: Assume that $\matQ$ is an invertible matrix
($\matQ^{-1} = \matQ^T$ is a special case). If $\matQ^{-1} \matD
\matQ$ is diagonal, then the columns of $\matQ$ are the eigenvectors
of $\matD$. Proof: We express $\matQ$ by its columns $\matQ =
\pmat{\vecq_1 & \ldots & \vecq_n}$. Since $\matQ$ is invertible, the
columns of $\matQ$ span the entire $\mathbb{R}^n$ (since the $n$
columns must be linearly independent). Thus
any vector can be expressed as a superposition of the column
vectors, also the vector $\matD \vecq_i$:

\begin{equation}
  \matD \vecq_i = \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} \vecq_j.
\end{equation}

We look at column $i$ of $\matQ^{-1}\matD\matQ$:

\begin{eqnarray}
  (\matQ^{-1}\matD\matQ)\vece_i
  &=& \matQ^{-1}\matD\vecq_i\\
  &=& \matQ^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} \vecq_j\\
  &=& \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} \vece_j.
\end{eqnarray}

Since we assume that $\matQ^{-1}\matD\matQ$ is diagonal (i.e. equals
a diagonal matrix $\matD'$ with elements $d'_i$), we know that

\begin{eqnarray}
  (\matQ^{-1}\matD\matQ)\vece_i &=& d'_i \vece_i\\
  \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} \vece_j &=& d'_i \vece_i
\end{eqnarray}

thus $a_{ii} = d'_i$ and $a_{ij} = 0$, $\forall j \neq i$. Therefore
the superposition equation above turns into

\begin{equation}
  \matD \vecq_i = d'_i \vecq_i,\quad i = 1,\ldots,n.
\end{equation}

We see that the vectors $\vecq_i$, $i=1,\ldots,n$, are the
eigenvectors of $\matD$, which concludes the proof of statement
2.

According to statement 1, the eigenvectors of $\matD$ are the basis
vectors $\pm \vece_j$, and according to statement 2, the
eigenvectors of $\matD$ are the columns $\vecq_i$. The assignment
of $j$ to $i$ can be any permutation $\pi$:

\begin{equation}
  \vecq_i = \pm\vece_{\pi(i)}
\end{equation}

which concludes the proof of the Lemma.